# Scrolling fragment comes on top of Activity cause below activity view to scroll

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an activity which has `CoordinatorLayout` as a root layout. Inside that, there's a `FrameLayout` layout which is hidden and programmatically has been set a fragment which is revealed from the bottom on a button click. That fragment consists of a grid `RecyclerView` which is scrollable.

[refer to this](https://gfycat.com/BriskHorribleAfricanpiedkingfisher)

If you focus on the toolbar you can see behind view gets scroll down and shows the behind view image when the grid view scroll content is over.

This is the layout of my activity

**Activity Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".activities.hotels.HotelDetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBar"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:titleEnabled="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_hotel_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/temp_hotel"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tool_bar_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                        android:text="Hotel Name"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tool_bar_sub_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Thu, 10 Jan 2019 - Sat, 12 Jan 2019"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tool_bar_title" />

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/more_detail_fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_library"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_message_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@drawable/clickable_bottom_bar_background"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_message_container_child"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:text="LKR 0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detail_titel_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                android:text="Starting From"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/continue_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/secondary_button_background"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/button_color"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:text="Continue"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Fragment Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".fragments.hotels.AllHotelAmenitiesFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hotel_amenities_title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:text="Hotel Amenities"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/divider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler_view_expand_layout"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/main_hotel_amenities_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**HotelDetailActivity**

```
public class HotelDetailActivityEdit extends AppCompatActivity{

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @BindView(R.id.more_detail_fragment_holder)
    FrameLayout allHotelAmenityHolder;

    @BindView(R.id.app_bar)
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout;

    @BindView(R.id.recycler_view_expand_layout)
    FrameLayout recyclerViewExpandLayout;

    private boolean allAmenitiesFragmentIsHidden;

    private Animation revealFromBottom;
    private Animation unRevealFromBottom;
    private AllHotelAmenitiesFragment allHotelAmenitiesFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotel_detail);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        initialization();
        onClickHotelAmenityExpandContainer();
    }

    private void initialization() {

        revealFromBottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
        unRevealFromBottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);

        allAmenitiesFragmentIsHidden = true;

        allHotelAmenitiesFragment = new AllHotelAmenitiesFragment();

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);

    }


    private void onClickHotelAmenityExpandContainer() {
        recyclerViewExpandLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (allAmenitiesFragmentIsHidden) {
                    allHotelAmenityHolder.startAnimation(revealFromBottom);
                    allHotelAmenityHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
                    allAmenitiesFragmentIsHidden = false;
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        if (!allAmenitiesFragmentIsHidden)
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_close);
        else {
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_arrow_back);
        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (!allAmenitiesFragmentIsHidden) {
            allHotelAmenityHolder.startAnimation(unRevealFromBottom);
            allHotelAmenityHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
            allAmenitiesFragmentIsHidden = true;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

**AllHotelAmenitiesFragment**

```
public class AllHotelAmenitiesFragment extends Fragment {


    @BindView(R.id.main_hotel_amenities_recycler_view)
    RecyclerView mainHotelAmenitiesRecyclerView;


    private MainHotelAmenitiesListAdapter mainHotelAmenitiesListAdapter;

    public AllHotelAmenitiesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public void setArguments(ArrayList<HotelAmenitiesImageObject> hotelAmenitiesWithImages) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList("hotel_amenities", hotelAmenitiesWithImages);
        this.setArguments(args);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_hotel_amenities, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        initialization();

        return view;
    }

    private void initialization() {

        ArrayList<HotelAmenitiesImageObject> mainHotelAmenities = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("hotel_amenities");

        mainHotelAmenitiesListAdapter = new MainHotelAmenitiesListAdapter(mainHotelAmenities);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4);
        GridRecyclerViewDivider gridRecyclerItemDecorator = new GridRecyclerViewDivider(4, 16, true, 0);
        mainHotelAmenitiesRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(gridRecyclerItemDecorator);
        mainHotelAmenitiesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        mainHotelAmenitiesRecyclerView.setAdapter(mainHotelAmenitiesListAdapter);

    }

}
```

As you can see I have set `android:clickable="true"` to the root layout of the fragment which is what usually do to stop registering clicks on behind layout. It seems when it's come to scroll it does not work like that.

I don't want my activity view behind my fragment to react to the scroll when my fragment visible. Please give me a suggestion to fix this bug.

Comment: what's in your `<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />` layout file? are you using this?

Comment: It's the scrolling content which is a `NestedScrollView` as a root layout inside that a `ConstraintLayout` and that contains all other elements.

Comment: Ok as highlighted in answer I suspect the issue is your frame layout which will have the fragment is floating in no-man's land. You want *all* content inside the nested scroll view. Move the fragment inside the nested scrollview in content scrolling then, then the behaviour should work.

Comment: you don't want your appBarLayout react with fragment recyclerview scroll or you don't want your `content_scrolling` layout scroll when fragment recylcerview scroll.

Comment: When Fragment is visible I don't want my appBarLayout to react to fragment recycler view scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run a demo, this works! It is the [Gif links](https://gfycat.com/RemorsefulOffbeatIbizanhound)

- **code block one**

`disable the AppBarLayout scroll event to expand or collapse`

- **code block two**

`disable the recyclerview scroll event to expand or collapse AppBarLayout`

`you can use scroll flag to disable it too, which i have comment, but this way will expand the AppBarLayout first`

You can use these two code block to get what you want.

**You should modified these code for your project**

when fragment visible, `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mRecyclerView, false)` to disable your fragment's recyclerview not your `content_scrolling` layout recyclerview.

```
private int state = STATE_APPBAR;
private static final int STATE_APPBAR = 1;
private static final int STATE_CONTENT = 2;


CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mAppBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.setBehavior(new AppBarLayout.Behavior());
AppBarLayout.Behavior appBarBehavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
//code block one
if (appBarBehavior != null) {
    appBarBehavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
        @Override
        public boolean canDrag(@NonNull AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
            return state == STATE_APPBAR;
        }
    });
}

//code block two
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (state == STATE_APPBAR) {
            state = STATE_CONTENT;
            //setAppbarLayoutScrollFlag(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP);
            ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mRecyclerView, false);
        } else {
            state = STATE_APPBAR;
            //setAppbarLayoutScrollFlag(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED);
            ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mRecyclerView, true);
        }
    }
});


private void setAppbarLayoutScrollFlag(int flags) {
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams lp = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) mToolbarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    lp.setScrollFlags(flags);
    mToolbarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

**Apply the code in your project**

1. add a method in `AllHotelAmenitiesFragment` to get recyclerview

```
public class AllHotelAmenitiesFragment extends Fragment {


    @BindView(R.id.main_hotel_amenities_recycler_view)
    RecyclerView mainHotelAmenitiesRecyclerView;


    private MainHotelAmenitiesListAdapter mainHotelAmenitiesListAdapter;

    public AllHotelAmenitiesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    
    public RecyclerView getRecyclerView() {
       return mainHotelAmenitiesRecyclerView;
    }
```

2. In your `HotelDetailActivityEdit` add block logic

```
private void onClickHotelAmenityExpandContainer() {
        recyclerViewExpandLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (allAmenitiesFragmentIsHidden) {
                    allHotelAmenityHolder.startAnimation(revealFromBottom);
                    allHotelAmenityHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
                    allAmenitiesFragmentIsHidden = false;
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();

                    //add block logic
                    RecyclerView recyclerview = allHotelAmenitiesFragment.getRecyclerView();
                    ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerview, false);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have added activity and fragment code to the question. Can you explain what is this `mRecyclerView` in this "code block 2"? As I understood it should be in my `onClickHotelAmenityExpandContainer()` method. if `mRecyclerView` my recycler view in fragment, How can I get a reference to that? please check added Java code.

Comment: @ChathurangaShanJayarathna  i have update my answer, add some logic in your project, take a look.

Comment: It worked. I was stuck 2 days in this problem. Thanks.

Comment: @ChathurangaShanJayarathna  Cheers mate!  I would appreciate that if you award the bounty to my answer

Comment: I did and pop up message satid it would apply after 18 hours.

Answer (score 0):

For the collapsing toolbar and scrolling behaviour to work properly in CoordinatorLayout, you need to define the `layout_behaviour` in the content layout.

You have an `<include/>` layout directly above your frame, I suspect this will have the correct layout attributes, so your frame layout is sort of "floating" in no-man's land.

```
<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/more_detail_fragment_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

You probably want the frame layout sitting inside a `<NestedScrollView>`, and then I guess you may not be using the include so just delete that. Something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/more_detail_fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Still, Both of the views gets scroll down and up together.